# Symlink to jar in /usr/bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: java, file-format, 22.04

I'm a bit puzzled on Ubuntu 22.04, I installed the `ditaa` package, which is a java program providing a jar in `/usr/share/ditaa/ditaa.jar` that is supposed to be run with `java -jar /usr/share/ditaa/ditaa.jar`. The package also provides a symlink in `/usr/bin/ditaa` to the jar file, instead of a wrapper script. As a result, trying to run ditaa directly from shell (or from `system`) throws an error.

```
$ ditaa
bash: /usr/bin/ditaa: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu yet, I was expecting `/usr/bin/ditaa` to be a wrapper script like

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
java -jar /usr/share/ditaa/ditaa.jar $@
```

Is there a feature that I did not install so that bash is able to recognise java programs and run them using `java`? (I know that this feature exists to transparently run programs with different architectures over `qemu` using `binfmt`, but I found nothing provided for java.)

Comment: `binfmt` can do a lot more than run programs on QEMU - you can get it to call pretty much anything to execute a given file based on what the file contents start with. It's shebang on steroids.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Note: It's still in *alpha* with *beta-freeze* scheduled for 28-March, and *beta* release scheduled for 31-March-2022

Comment: @muru Thanks, that was what I was looking for. `update-binfmts --enable jar` did the trick.